# How to get the regex match without None

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-re

I am trying to find pattern matching with Regex. The used case is as follows:

```
listStrings1 = ['abc','def', 'ghi']
listSubstrings1 = ['a', 'b', 'e']
```

listStrings1 is the strings inputs and listSubstrings1 is the pattern which needed to be matched. so output should look like

```
['a', 'b'], ['b'], []
```

but currently I am getting like

```
['a', 'b', None], ['b', None, None], [None, None, None]
```

Here is what I tried so far

```
def research(substring, string):
    match = re.search(substring, string)
    emptystr = ''
    if match is not None:
        return emptystr
    else:
        return substring

def substringsearch(sublist, string):
    matchlist = list(map(lambda y: research(y, string), sublist ))
    return matchlist

listm1 = list(map(lambda x: substringsearch(listSubstrings1, x), listStrings1))
print(listm1)
```

Also time is another crucial factor as size of string input and substring input is around 100k so if possible without using loops.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: It’s not the answer, but you could always remove the Nones afterward.

Comment: That output is **not** what you're getting with that code. And if you want actual help with performance, you should tell more details about your data.

Comment: You should probably take a look at what a *list comprehension* is (and the related *generator expression*). ``map``, ``filter`` and friends have their place, but in such a case they are unwieldy.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The OP specifically wrote *"without using loops"*.

Comment: @AnnZen Note "if possible". ``map`` *is* a wrapper around a loop, so I would chalk that up as misunderstanding that they are already using a (doubly nested) loop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how optimized is this solution but its working and easy to understand and implement.

```
listStrings1 = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
listSubstrings1 = ['a', 'b', 'e']

all_matches = []
for s in listStrings1:
    matches = []
    for x in listSubstrings1:
        if x in s:
            matches.append(x)
    all_matches.append(matches)

print(all_matches)
```

output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['e'], []]
```

this code can be simplify into one-liner but I think its easier to understand this way.

Comment: I also got this solution but since the list size is too big, this is taking infinity to run, so anything without for loop will be much appreciated.

Comment: @AmitGupta Your initial code also has two ``for`` loops, they are just hidden behind ``map``.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the built-in [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function on the resulting `map` object before converting it to a list:

```
listm1 = list(filter(None, map(lambda x: substringsearch(listSubstrings1, x), listStrings1)))
```

Comment: Note that the corresponding list comprehension is shorter and most likely more readable to most people.